# From an Advaitic perspective, who set in motion the law of karma?

Tags: karma, advaita

According to Advaitins, who set in motion the law of karma?

Is it Saguna Brahman
or
Nirguna Brahman?

The vyavaharika satya or jagat along with its karma, rebirth etc. is not completely mithya. Its not completely true either.

When advaitins say it is mithya, they simply mean its not what it seems ... (i.e. this jagat along with its varieties is only nama-rupa, an apparent reality superimposed on the formless brahman).

So in advaita, the jagat is neither completely mithya nor  completely true. Its just an apparent, transactional and impermanent reality, and not the ultimate reality.

My point is, if jagat is not totally mithya, then law of karma (which operates in this jagat) is also not totally mithya.
So who set in motion the law of karma?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134479/discussion-on-question-by-the-crimson-universe-from-an-advaitic-perspective-who).

Answer (score 2):

No one set in motion the law of karma since the transmigratory state has no beginning.

> If it be argued that it is not possible (to take Karma - merit and
> demerit - into consideration in the beginning), since the fruits of
> work remain still undifferentiated, then we say, no, since **the
> transmigratory state has no beginning.**

**Brahma Sutra II.i.35**

> ...the transmigratory state has no beginning. .... if that state has
> no beginning, there is nothing contradictory for the fruits of work
> and the variety in creation to act as cause and effect of each other
> on the analogy of the seed and the sprout.
>
> How again is it known that this transmigratory state has no beginning?
>
> To this the answer is:

**Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankarachary II.i.35**

> Moreover, this is logical, and (so) it is met with (in the
> scriptures).

**Brahma Sutra II.i.36**

> And it is logical for the transmigratory existence to have no
> beginning; for had it emerged capriciously all of a sudden, then there
> would have been the predicament of freed souls also being reborn
> here, as also  the contingency of results accruing from non-existing
> causes, for the differences in happiness and misery would have no
> logical explanation. It has been pointed out already that God is not
> the cause of inequality, nor is ignorance by itself a source of this,
> it being homogeneous. Ignorance can at best become creator of
> inequality in consequence of the fruits of work, which are acquired as
> a result of the influence of past impressions of the three
> infatuations - love, hatred, and delusion. The fallacy of mutual
> dependence does not arise from the impossibility of bodies being
> created without karma and karma being performed without bodies; for if
> creation is beginningless, all this become reasonable on the analogy
> of the seed and the sprout, and hence there will be no defect.
>
> And we realize the beginningless of creation from the Vedas and the
> Smritis. In the Vedas, for instance, occurs the text, "Myself entering
> into this as the embodied soul (Jiva-atma - living being)" (Chandogya
> Upanishad Vi.iii.2). Referring to the beginning of creation, this text
> speaks of the embodied soul as the "living being" on account of its
> sustaining life, and thereby it shows that creation had no beginning;
> for if creation had a beginning then, since the soul had no life to
> sustain (at that time), why should the "living being" have been
> referred to in that text through the word jiva (living one) which
> comes into use from the fact of supporting the life process (jivana)?
> It cannot be that the term jiva is used in anticipation that it will
> support life in future; for an existing relationship is stronger than
> future one, inasmuch as the former is an accomplished fact. And the
> mantra text, "The Ordainer created the sun and moon like those of the
> previous cycles (Rig Veda X.cxc.3) shows the existence of earlier
> cycles of creation. In the Smriti also the transmigratory state is
> noticed to be without beginning, as in "Its form is not here perceived
> as such, neither its end, nor its origin, nor its continuance" (Gita
> XV.3). The conclusion made in the Puranas also is that the past and
> future cycles of creation are numberless.

**Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya II.i.36**

**A possible interpretation of the above commentary**

In the first paragraph of Sri Sankaracharya's commentary he is arguing that first creation will violate the principle of regularity. Any irregular event like first creation will make any logical explanation of happiness and misery impossible.

In the second paragraph he is quoting from various scriptures to support his position.

There is a minority view (not in Advaita Vedanta) that at the first creation all jivas were given a positive amount of karma.

Comment: You quoted Chandogya Upanishad saying "Myself entering into this embodied soul..." ... May i know who this 'Myself' is? ... Is it the Nirguna Nirakara Brahman becoming the jiva or is it Saguna Brahman?

Comment: To be honest, the language used in the Brahma Sutra verses that you quoted, are a little hard for me to grasp. I think a simple English translation of the B.S. or maybe a video that explains everything in lucid language would be really great ... For now I'll just have to accept that karma and maya are beginingless ... Also could you please explain how the jagat and jivas appear/manifest on the substratum? ... In other words, who's responsible for their manifestation? Is it Saguna Brahman or Nirguna Brahman? Thanks.

Comment: The Chandogya Upanishad is talking about Nirguna Brahman. Entering of Sat is not like entering of one thing into another. It is more like entering of the sun into water or a mirror by means of its reflection. The embodied creature appears when Sat comes into contact with the physical body and the sense-organs through Its reflection.

Comment: Brahman through Its Sakti manifests Jiva and Jagat. Saguna Brahman is simply Brahman as experienced by a person in the realm of Sakti. There are no 2 Brahmans.

Comment: You said Saguna Brahman is the same Brahman 'EXPERIENCED BY A PERSON' in the realm of shakti ... I agree he dwells in the realm of maya/shakti but does He exists only in the mind/experiences of a person? Doesn't He continues to exist (in his abode Brahmaloka or Vishnuloka) when jivas+physical universe becomes unmanifested upon cosmic annihilation (pralaya) and when our experiences ceases?? ... Its true that even such abodes of Ishwara lies in the realm of shakti/maya but what i'm trying to say is, He does exist irrespective of our 'human experiences' ... Won't you agree with me on this? :)

Comment: By person I meant a Jiva. Bhakti literature says that Vishnuloka exists eternally and is not affected by any Pralaya or when the universe ceases to exist. There Brahman will continue to be experienced as what Advaita Vedanta calls Saguna Brahman and what Vaishnavas will call Vishnu or Narayana. The case of Brahmaloka is different. I think Brahmaloka will cease to exist during mahapralaya and Jivas there will then gain moksha.

Comment: Thanks. Can a mukta-advaitin  after death merge with saguna brahman? or do you think advaitins only merge with nirguna nirakar brahman?

Comment: Only with nirguna Brahman.

Answer (score 1):

Nirguna Brahman  or Shuddha chaitanyam is

‘nishkalam, nishkriyam, shantam, niravadyam, niranjanam’(without form, action.. tranquil,limitless and blemishless(Svetashvatara Upanishad VI.19 )

is unmanifest  and so it is neither the karta or bhokta and has nothing to do with karma.

(Ashtavakra Gita 15.4
na tvaṃ deho na te deho bhoktā kartā na vā bhavān |
cidrūpo'si sadā sākṣī nirapekṣaḥ sukhaṃ cara || 4 ||)

When the same chaitanyam manifests with its
unscrutable power  Maya (trigunathmika),

it  is called Maya
avachinna(scoped by) chaitanyam
(conscious ness)responsible for the functions of creation(Brahma), preservation (Vishnu)and dissolution (shiva)

of entire Existence.otherwise known as Ishwara

mAyA is nothing but prakRRiti or nature (mAyAntu prakRitim vidyAt mAyinantu maheswaram) Svet. Up. IV-10;

Let me be born (as many)’ - tad aikshata bahu syAm, prajAyeya" (Ch. Up. VI-2-3)

Hence created Jivas which are Avidya avachinna chaitanyam.

Jiva(vyashti) is the karta and Ishwara(samashti) is the karma phala dhata(nigraham, anugraham)
in accordance to karma)
verse506 SVSSS of HH Adishankara

Verse 511 of svsss of HH Adishankara  says

karrmana jayate jantuhu karmanaiva praliyate
karmanaha karyamevaisha
janma mrutyu parampara

Karma is the reason for birth death cycle

BG 7.20

kamais tais tair hrita-jnanah prapadyante ’nya-devatah
tam tam niyamam asthaya prakritya niyatah svaya

carried away by their own nature prakruthi(satva rajas tams composition) one choose their saguna deity and surrender.

BG 7.21

yo yo yāṁ yāṁ tanuṁ bhaktaḥ śhraddhayārchitum ichchhati
tasya tasyāchalāṁ śhraddhāṁ tām eva vidadhāmyaham

HH shankaras commentary
By Swami Gambirananda

Whichever form (of a deity) any devotee wants to worship with faith, that very firm faith of his I strengthen.

Nama Rupa saguna brahaman is resorted for upasana owing to the limitation of antahkarana.
whose effect is a samskara

But HH Shankara says Jnanam cannot be effect of any karma including upasana which is the manasika karma, as the effect caused by karma can only  fall under 4 categories uthpathi, Aapthi, Vikruthi, samskruti.

Comment: You wrote "Jiva(vyashti) is the karta and Ishwara(samashti) is the karma phala dhata(nigraham, anugraham) in accordance to karma) verse506 SVSSS of HH Adishankara" ... What did you mean by vyashti, samashti, karma phala dhata, nigraham, anugraham? ... Since i don't understand sanskrit or hindi, could you translate these words in English? ... Also utpati, samskruti, vikruti, aapti.

Comment: vyashti is the individual entity  and samashti is its collection(cosmic)like tree and the forest
.. As how  Jiva Identifies with himself (his body and mind).Samashti identifies with all the jivas.akin to conscious ness of forest that identify all trees. karma phala dhata  is one who grants the effect of a an action whose cause is karma. anugraham is bestow . and nigraham is the opposite of it .. decline.. uthpathi is produce , like creating a pot.. Aapthi is procurring  what is available like getting milk. . Vikruthi is change like chemical reaction.. and samskruti is modifying a habit

Comment: Jnani is for one whom ahankara ( I ness) is obliterated , consequence of which is he becomes the I ( I ness, Identify with  ) for samashti. Jnani identifies withh all jivas akin to how a Jiva feels his own identity of his body and mind

Comment: karta means doer

Comment: Thanks. In your original answer you said "WHEN the unmanifested, nirguna brahman manifests as Ishwara etc. etc." ...... By using the word "WHEN" are you saying that there comes a time when the unmanifest nirguna brahman becomes manifest? ... In other words, does Ishwara's form remains manifested forever (for all eternity)? ... OR does Ishwara's form (just like the rest of Jiva's forms) becomes Unmanifest at a certain point in time and again becomes manifest at a certain point in time?

Comment: The analogy of tree and seed, does not answer the question which came first, (still one have specify a solution.. adhyaropa apavadha details it ,but that would be too much  of research) This transfers to the problem of karma an janma , HH Shankara in his commentary on K.Upanishas says the chain is beginning less(aNadhi).so Maya is beginning less implying Ishwara is beginning less.. May be understanding Einstens relativity of time could be some  extent relatable to this .

Comment: karma means action ( thought as well) ignorant of one's own true nature
janma..means birth begets further bondage

Comment: If your question is , does Ishwara switch between the state of manifest an unmanifest time and again,.. yes.At the time of pralaya(dissolution) Ishwara retreats to causal body (karana sharira) is unmanifest .You may find in puranas or easily in Duruva stuti  that Ishwara holds all jivas in potential in his stomach till the next creation

Comment: But as per the gaudiya vaishnavas,  Vishnu, even during pralaya, continues to exist in his four handed form and lies in a spiritual ocean called Karana-Jala, where he absorbs all the jivas in his body till the next creation. But you said Ishwara unmanifests in his causal body. I'm confused.

Comment: True.Vishnu lies on karana jala  in cosmic sleep known as yoga nidra. which ends with the begining of the next creation.So supposedly Ishwara is unmanifest till next creation. (unmanifest doesn't mean non existent, it's a potential state prior to manifestation)

Comment: True, unmanifest doesn't mean non-existent. And that's not what i meant. Un-manifest or avyakta, actually means something that which is devoid of form (as per wiki) and is not perceptible to our senses. But in the case of vishnu lying in karana jala or even in his abode Vaikuntha, he retains his form (four hands and so on). So what made you say Vishnu or Ishwara becomes unmanifest (devoid of anthropomorphic form during pralaya)? When the truth is, He continues to remain in form even during pralaya, while the rest of the jivas & material jagat becomes unmanifest. Would you agree with me   here?

Comment: owing to adhikari bheda , purusha suktam conveys the same idea wherein Lord Vishnu is conceived as a cosmic being (samashti) (pādo'sya viśvā bhūtāni...pādo'syehābhavātpunaḥ )whose quater or a portion  is the material world(bhutani-out of five primordial elements) is only annihilated and recreated ,implying there is no manifestation.In essence lord is beyond all possibilities of human understanding , (jneya Brahmam) , all power all knowledge, whose auspicious form occuring in puranas  could be the inspired vision of sages . srimad bhagavadam 2.6.11 conveys  the same idea

Comment: avyakta-rasa-sindhūnāṁ
bhūtānāṁ nidhanasya ca
udaraṁ viditaṁ puṁso
hṛdayaṁ manasaḥ padam ...